# get distinct value from two table in mysql

Tags: mysql

> Blockquote
>   table homework

```
sr_no  homework_date  homework
1        2019-02-01   essay
2        2019-02-03   some stuff
2        2019-02-06   some stuff
```

table classwork

```
sr_no  classwork_date  classwork
1        2019-02-01   essay
1        2019-02-02   essay
2        2019-02-04   some stuff
2        2019-02-05  some stuff
```

result will be like this
date

```
2019-02-01
2019-02-02
2019-02-03
2019-02-04
2019-02-05
2019-02-06
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below using left and right join and merge two dataset by UNION

```
select coalesce(classwork_date,homework_date) as date
from classwork left join homework on classwork_date=homework_date
union 
select coalesce(classwork_date,homework_date)
from classwork right join homework on classwork_date=homework_date
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 SELECT 
    homework_date
FROM
    homework 
UNION SELECT 
    classwork_date
FROM
    classwork
ORDER BY homework_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
homework_date
FROM
homework 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT
classwork_date
FROM
classwork
ORDER BY homework_date;
```

Comment: There is no need to use the `DISTINCT` keyword here as it is redundant since `UNION` does that already (eliminating duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly (and explaining your questions in more words would have probably helper) What you are looking for is to retrieve the date columns from both tables and show them order by date.

A classic solution to retrieve data from two or more tables is the [`UNION`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) operator. The `UNION` operator by itself will not complete the task because you also want the results order by date. You can add an `ORDER BY` clause to the last `SELECT`, using the first table field name, because `UNION` will fit the data from the column of the additional table into the correct column in the initial result set (by specification order), so you can just sort on the column names from the first select, and it will sort the entire result set.

`UNION` does eliminate duplicate results, so you should not need the `DISTINCT` keyword in your select query.